# Hoare Partition Correctness in java

Tags: java, quicksort

I am working to implement a Hoare partition into a quicksort. I am trying to completely understand the hoare partition but the book doesnt explain everything. Mainly I am just wondering what the while TRUE part means? The excerpt from the book is below. If I were to put the while part in java what would I use and why?

```
Hoare-Partition(A,p,r)
    x= A[p]
    i = p-1
    j=r+1
    while true
        repeat
            j=j-1
        until A [j] <= x
        repeat
            i = i +1
        until A[i] >= x
        if i < l
           exchange A[i] with A[j]
        else return j
```

Comment: `while true` may mean to indicate a Infinite loop. java code: while(true)

Comment: I guess that makes sense, let me post the rest of the code that might be necessary if that is the case

Comment: yeah... there should be a `break` somewhere in there

Comment: I have never messed with an infinite loop like that and have never seen it in pseudo code like that

Comment: see if the below code in my answer works out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code for the algo that you have above :

```
int HoarePartition (int a[],int p, int r) 
{
    int x=a[p],i=p-1,j=r+1;
    while (true) 
    {
        while (a[j] <= x) j--; 
        while (a[i] >= x) i++;
        if  (i < j) swap(a[i],a[j]);
        else return j;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect because the logic does not match the original pseudocode. The semantics of the pseudocode's `repeat ... until (condition)` should be written in Java as `while (not condition) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working translation:

```
  public static void quicksort(int[] ar) {
    if (ar == null) return;
    quicksort(ar, 0, ar.length-1);
  }

  private static void quicksort(int[] ar, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo < hi) {
      int splitPoint = partition(ar, lo, hi);
      quicksort(ar, lo, splitPoint);
      quicksort(ar, splitPoint+1, hi);
    }
  }

  private static int partition(int[] ar, int lo, int hi) {
    int pivot = ar[lo];
    int i = lo-1, j = hi+1;
    while(true) {
      do { i++; } while(ar[i] < pivot);
      do { j--; } while(ar[j] > pivot);
      if (i < j) swap(ar, i, j);
      else return j;
    }
  }

  private static void swap(int[] ar, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = ar[i];
    ar[i] = ar[j];
    ar[j] = tmp;
  }
```